# How can I split a midi file programatically?

Tags: midi, midi-controller-keyboard, computer

Im using the mido library on python to work with the midi file.

Given any midi file, I would like to output a midi file consisting only of the first 10 seconds of the input. I don't see any functions to do this in the library, so im trying to do this through going through each of the tracks.

Im finding a few things confusing. For example, below is what you get when you examine a single track in your midi object.

```
<meta message track_name name='Slow Strings' time=0>
program_change channel=0 program=49 time=0
program_change channel=0 program=49 time=0
control_change channel=0 control=7 value=71 time=0
control_change channel=0 control=10 value=75 time=0
note_on channel=0 note=55 velocity=89 time=15360
note_on channel=0 note=59 velocity=95 time=0
note_on channel=0 note=62 velocity=92 time=0
note_off channel=0 note=55 velocity=64 time=1324
note_off channel=0 note=62 velocity=64 time=12
```

So do I go through this list of messages in the track and count the time attribute until the running sum exceeds 10000 (milliseconds)? I don't think so, because looking at the piece on musescore, nothing significant haappens 15.36 seconds into the song.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984608/midi-delta-time), that the times aren't in milliseconds, but delta times, which must be converted to milliseconds through PPQ (pulses per quater note). Is this correct, and if so is using a running sum of time the right approach to creating an output midi of time 10 seconds?

Comment: See: https://sites.uci.edu/camp2014/2014/05/19/timing-in-midi-files/

Comment: Does it have to be within python...? You could simply go to http://midi.mathewvp.com/midiTrim.htm upload the whole midi file, type 0 to 10 seconds and download the trimmed version again. This may be the fastest way, but you could also do this within any DAW if you want.

Answer (score 2):

The times are not in milliseconds, they're in midi ticks which you can convert to seconds with the function `tick2second(ticks, ticks_per_beat, tempo)`. Your code should look something like this:

```
from mido import MidiFile
from mido import tick2second

mid = MidiFile('input.mid')

for i, track in enumerate(mid.tracks):
    total_time = 0
    for msg in track:
        if msg.type == 'set_tempo':
            tempo = msg.tempo
        total_time  += tick2second(msg.time, mid.ticks_per_beat, tempo)
        print(msg, total_time) # or copy to output file
        if total_time > 10:
            break
```

Note: this assumes there are no tempo changes in the first 10 seconds of your input files. If there are your code will need to be more complex.

Answer (score -1):

If you're OK with C# instead of Python, you can use [DryWetMIDI](https://github.com/melanchall/drywetmidi) library. The code to take first 10 seconds of a MIDI file is super easy:

```
var midiFile = MidiFile.Read("My MIDI file.mid");
var newMidiFile = midiFile.TakePart(new MetricTimeSpan(0, 0, 10));
newMidiFile.Write("10sec version.mid");
```